# how can I get hyperlinks from a webpage iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, html, web-services, url

I want to get links of from a web page.. I have been successful in parsing the html now all i want are their links... do you have any idea as to how can i get those hyperlinks? any help would be appreciated....

thanks

Comment: Define "successful in parsing the html". Using my definition you already have the links.

Comment: Ditto rcravens...how are you parsing the html? Normally you'd just grab the attribute 'href' within the link tag.